# Subsetting only the workdays from a time-series

Tags: r, date, time-series, subset, forecasting

I want to subset only the workdays from the time series `taylor`, in the `forecast` package.

```
help(taylor)
```

> ```
> Half-hourly electricity demand in England and Wales from Monday 5 June 2000 to 
> Sunday 27 August 2000. Discussed in Taylor (2003), and kindly provided by James
> W Taylor. Units: Megawatts
> ```

but the times of the time series are not dates, they are 1-based numbers representing days from the series start:

```
time(head(taylor))  
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 6) 
Frequency = 336 
[1] 1.000000 1.002976 1.005952 1.008929 1.011905 1.014881
```

how do I convert these to dates, extract only the workdays samples, and create a new time-series with a frequency of `5*24*2` (instead of the original frequency of `7*24*2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a *"half-hourly"* date sequence with the start and end date given in the description of `taylor`.

```
data("taylor", package="forecast")

dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-06-05"), as.POSIXct("2000-08-28"), "30 min")
dates <- dates[-length(dates)]  # exclude "2000-08-28 00:00:00"
```

Now, using `substr()`, we may exclude `weekdays()` starting with an `"S"` (may not work in other languages) and create a new "ts" object with specific start, end, frequency values.

```
taylor2 <- ts(taylor[!substr(weekdays(dates), 1, 1) == "S"], start=1, end=12, frequency=240)
```

It is better, though, to create a `"msts"` object using the `forecast` library to maintain the same seasonality.

```
library(forecast)
taylor3 <- msts(taylor[!substr(weekdays(dates), 1, 1) == "S"], seasonal.periods=c(24*2, 24*2*5))
```

#### check

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
plot(taylor)
plot(taylor2)
plot(taylor3)
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: why do we need to use cycle? what's wrong with using your exact answer without the `[cycle(taylor)]` part?

Comment: @ihadanny Good point. The values didn't match up with the `ts` object and I first thought they needed sorting. Actually we logically need to make the sequence one day longer and exclude the last midnight, so it gives exactly the `length(taylor)` values. See update!

Comment: thanks, just one more thing - what's `end` and why do you set it to 12? I think the correct command is `taylor2 <- msts(taylor[!substr(weekdays(dates), 1, 1) == "S"], seasonal.periods = c(24*2, 24*2*5))`

Comment: @ihadanny The `end == 12` refer to the weeks (as it was set before), check `length(taylor)/(2*24*7)` and `table(cycle(taylor))`.

Comment: Ah! I see. I checked, and it works with the `msts` call as well, I'll edit your answer as without this the new `taylor2` series loses the multi-seasonality of the original `taylor` series.

Comment: @ihadanny that's ok for me

Answer (score 1):

You might consider converting the time-series to an `xts`-object to allow for easier data manipulation. For instance, we can extract the weekdays from an `xts`-object using `.indexwkday`:

```r
library(xts)

## load data
data(taylor, package = "forecast")

## convert to xts
taylor_xts <- xts(
    x = taylor,
    order.by = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2000-06-05"), length = length(taylor), by = "30 min")
)

## extract weekdays
taylor_wk <- taylor_xts[.indexwday(taylor_xts) %in% 1:5]

head(taylor_wk); tail(taylor_wk)
#>                      [,1]
#> 2000-06-05 00:00:00 22262
#> 2000-06-05 00:30:00 21756
#> 2000-06-05 01:00:00 22247
#> 2000-06-05 01:30:00 22759
#> 2000-06-05 02:00:00 22549
#> 2000-06-05 02:30:00 22313
#>                      [,1]
#> 2000-08-25 21:00:00 33064
#> 2000-08-25 21:30:00 31953
#> 2000-08-25 22:00:00 30548
#> 2000-08-25 22:30:00 29236
#> 2000-08-25 23:00:00 27623
#> 2000-08-25 23:30:00 26063
```

Or, if instead we wish to extract only data from office hours (weekdays between 9am-6pm):

```
## extract office hours
taylor_offh <- taylor_xts[.indexwday(taylor_xts) %in% 1:5 & .indexhour(taylor_xts) >= 9 & .indexhour(taylor_xts) < 18]

head(taylor_offh); tail(taylor_offh)
#>                      [,1]
#> 2000-06-05 09:00:00 36834
#> 2000-06-05 09:30:00 37296
#> 2000-06-05 10:00:00 37338
#> 2000-06-05 10:30:00 37608
#> 2000-06-05 11:00:00 37692
#> 2000-06-05 11:30:00 37944
#>                      [,1]
#> 2000-08-25 15:00:00 35067
#> 2000-08-25 15:30:00 34928
#> 2000-08-25 16:00:00 34738
#> 2000-08-25 16:30:00 35004
#> 2000-08-25 17:00:00 34748
#> 2000-08-25 17:30:00 34090
```

---

NB: plotting the sub-sampled time-series with `plot.xts` displays the date-times on the x-axis and therefore includes gaps at the weekends, (since the time-series is no longer sampled at regular intervals). To plot the data as a concatenated series use `plot.default` (or `plot.ts` after converting back to a `ts`-object).

```r
## plot time-series along time
plot(taylor_wk)
```

[image]

```r
## plot time-series along index 
plot.default(taylor_wk, type = "l")    ## equivalently `plot(coredata(taylor_wk), type = "l")`
```

[image]

Comment: looks very elegant, but it's not quite what I expected... please plot `taylor_wk` and see for yourself: it's not a concatenated series without the weekends, it's the same timeline, with a 2-days gap every weekend

Comment: @ihadanny: `plot(taylor_wk)` calls `plot.xts` which uses the timestamps of the time series for the x-axis. If you want to plot the data as a concatenated series, try `plot.ts(taylor_wk)`, or `plot(ts(taylor_wk, start = 1, frequency = 240))` (which also calls `plot.ts`) for a more sensible x-axis.